# Sharepoint Server 2010 Layout change

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 2 questions about sharepoint 2010.

1. When will Sharepoint Server 2010 released ?
2. Is Sharepoint Server 2010 easy customized in terms of layout aspect ?

   Description:We have a government client. They care UI more than other aspects such as functionality. So this B/S project will have a very customizable UI, and the client is highly likely to modify the UI at any time. I have reviewed Sharepoint Server 2010 that it is easy to make different themes, but I am wondering if it is still easy to modify website's layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 has already been released to RTM and is available through an MSDN subscription.
As for customization... It's as customizable as you want it to be, and even more so than 2007.
If they are going to modify the UI at any time, what elements are you talking about?  The masterpage? layout pages, or just content withing the sites?

Themes are simple css files that don't do much more than change styles,fonts, colors etc.  Masterpages give you all the muscle of ASP.NET so you can pretty much go to town on them.  You do need to be careful of the new Ribbon UI though.